# How to retrieve analytics on a post made by my Facebook App

Tags: facebook-graph-api, analytics, facebook-insights

I have a Facebook app that posts pictures to users' feeds using the graph API. I want to find out how many other Facebook users view each picture that gets posted. I have tried using the insights API, but it only returns empty data. For example, suppose a post has the ID:

```
100003858263437_217258205079453
```

If I visit:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100003858263437_217258205079453/insights?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The returned data is empty:

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/100003858263437_217258205079453/insights?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&since=-86400&until=0",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100003858263437_217258205079453/insights?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&since=0&until=86400"
   }
}
```

It seems from the Insights documentation that getting insights on a particular post may not be possible. Anyone know how to get Insights for a post made by an application?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, there is no pulling insights for User accounts. You can only pull insights for  pages, applications, and domains the user owns if you have the `read_insights` permission

Comment: Do you know if there is any other way to get the number of impressions/views of a photo that I post to a users account?

Comment: No, there is no other way. Facebook does not release insights for user accounts to anyone.